# Discord.JS/Mongoose Error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" at path "cashBalance"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I'm making an economy system for my discord bot, some of you are here to (try to) fix the mongoose problem so you don't need to worry too much about that.

I am making a "deposit" command, which takes a certain amount of cash from your balance and puts it in your "bank".

The part where I save the amount of cash to the bank works, but the part where I subtract the amount of cash from the balance (to make it look like you took money out of your cash balance) does not work. I get this error. `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" at path "cashBalance"`

Code (that has to do with this error):

```js
if (!isNaN(parseInt(args[0]))) {
  console.log('is a num')

  await depositModel.updateOne({ bankBalance: parseInt(args[0]) }).then(async () => {
    await depositModel.updateOne({ cashBalance: depositModel.cashBalance - parseInt(args[0]) })
  })

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('GREEN')
    .setDescription(`Successfully deposited ${parseInt(args[0])} to your bank!`)
    .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
    .setTimestamp()
  return message.channel.send(embed); 
} else {
  console.log('not num')
}
```

Comment: In your model, what is `cashBalance`?

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti basically the balance of cash you have, lets say you earned $500 from work, that would be your cash balance automatically. It is also a Number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason you're not using the [`$inc` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) to update your fields? You don't need all that async-await and `.then()` in your code:

```js
const amount = parseInt(args[0]);

if (isNaN(amount)) {
  console.log('not num');
  return;
}

await depositModel.updateOne({
  $inc: {
    bankBalance: amount,
    cashBalance: amount * -1,
  },
});

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('GREEN')
  .setDescription(`Successfully deposited ${amount} to your bank!`)
  .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
  .setTimestamp();
  
return message.channel.send(embed);
```